# What is making my model predicting the wrong value when running on my laptop and colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've exported a TF model to `.h5` format to use it for my project. When running and testing on Colab, it predicts perfectly but when I tried to predict the `.h5` format model in my machine(laptop), it did not predict the correct one therefore it did not work like it used to in Colab. I've tried to browse in the net but did not seem to find an answer or a clue. Does anyone know where the problem might be?

Example
Input image: dog type of `golden_retriever`

**(COLAB)** -> predicts `golden_retriever` (correct)

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model_mac.h5", custom_objects={"KerasLayer": hub.KerasLayer})
custom_images_paths = ["golde.jpeg"]
custom_data = create_data_batches(custom_images_paths, test_data=True)
custom_preds = model.predict(custom_data)
custom_pred_labels = [get_pred_label(custom_preds[i]) for i in range(len(custom_preds))]
```

**(MY MACHINE/LAPTOP)** -> predicts `norwegian_elkhound` (something else that does not look like a `golden_retriever`. (wrong)

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model_mac.h5", custom_objects {"KerasLayer":hub.KerasLayer})

img = "golde.jpeg"

custom_data = create_data_batches([img], test_data=True)
custom_preds = model.predict(custom_data)
custom_pred_labels = [get_pred_label(custom_preds[i]) for i in range(len(custom_preds))]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the outputs of each step of your model prediction code.

Are you able to verify your model gets the same results when you call `model.evaluate()` on a test split of the dataset?

That's one of the first things I'd try to do.

Otherwise, you might want to check out the part of the docs dealing with saving to `.h5`: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#hdf5_format

See the "Saving custom objects" section, have you defined the `hub.KerasLayer` on your local machine? Perhaps that has something to do with it.

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks for helping out. I've logged every single operation before and after predicting the custom images. I've also reevaluated the model on the test dataset, nothing wrong happens, model looks fine, accuracy doing fine and I've also checked the `.h5` format documentation that you've provided and it's still predicting the wrong output. I've tried to use the SavedModel format and it still predicts the wrong output.